# Why does the first hash mark disappear in a vim fold?

Tags: perl, vim

I am using manual folding to write perl programs. Here is a typical fold:

```
sub do_something # does something --{{{
{
    # perl code here
} # --}}}
```

When folded, these four lines are displayed thus:

```
+-- 4 lines: sub do_something does something ----------------------------
```

In the folded version, the hash mark before the word "does" has disappeared. Why? If this is a feature, how can I disable it? As a workaround, I am writing 'sub do_something ## does something --{{{', but is there a clean way to get vim to just display what I have typed? (Maybe this has something to do with perl.vim?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What gets displayed instead of the folded lines is controlled by the `'foldtext'` option. By default, the internal `foldtext()` function is used. `:help foldtext()` explains:

> ```
>   The returned string looks like this:
>       +-- 45 lines: abcdef
>   The number of dashes depends on the foldlevel.  The "45" is
>   the number of lines in the fold.  "abcdef" is the text in the
>   first non-blank line of the fold.  Leading white space, "//"
>   or "/*" and the text from the 'foldmarker' and 'commentstring'
>   options is removed.
> ```

As you see, this is a heuristic of Vim to reduce clutter. To turn that off:

1. You can clear `'commentstring'`; it is only used to add manual fold markers (and some commenting plugins may rely on it as a fallback), by putting `:setlocal commentstring=` into `~/.vim/after/ftplugin/perl.vim`.
2. You can write your own fold function (example and instructions at `:help fold-foldtext`), and install that, either globally or (like above alternative) only for the Perl filetype.